# Rewriting /latest produces server error

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

So I'm working on a site for a magazine, and I want the URL `/latest` to rewrite to the file `latest.php`. I'm working on a cPanel hosting server, so I put a `.htaccess` in the `/public_html` directory like so (important line is the 8th):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^archives/search/?$ /archives/search.php [L]
RewriteRule ^archives/([\d]{4})-([\d]{1})/?$ /archives/download.php?year=$1&issue=$2
RewriteRule ^archives/([\d]{4})/?$ /archives/download.php?year=$1
RewriteRule ^archives - [L]
RewriteRule ^admin - [L]
RewriteRule ^search - [L]
RewriteRule ^latest /latest.php [L]
RewriteRule ^contact/?$ /contact.php [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/?$ /page.php?p=$1 [L]

ErrorDocument 404 /notfound.php
ErrorDocument 500 /dberror.php
```

However, upon navigating to `/latest`, I get a `500 interal server error`. I originally thought it was some problem in the `.php` file, but that was ruled out when I completely emptied the file latest.php and the error persisted. Interestingly, when I change the `/latest` to anything else and navigate to that, it works. I have no idea why. I'd like to give the link to the full site, but it's still under development so I am not allowed to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your rewrite rule may be a non-sense to the server:

```
RewriteRule ^latest /latest.php [L]
```

Means "if someone wants to access to something that **begins with** "`latest`" then go to "`/latest.php`".

So the scenario is: you try to access to "`latest`", which is redirected to "`/latest.php`" then "`/latest.php`" is redirected to "`/latest.php`" and so on. It goes to an infinite redirection loop = `500 internal server error`.

This rule may be more appropriate:

```
RewriteRule ^latest(/|)$ /latest.php [L]
```

Which means: if there either the URL `latest` or `lastest/` then go to `/latest.php`

By the way I'd suggest to add non case sensitive = `NC` and query string append `QSA` to your rewriterule, this would end with something like:

```
RewriteRule ^latest(/|)$ /latest.php [QSA,NC,L]
```

Maybe this rule is the same, I didn't test:

```
RewriteRule ^latest/?$ /latest.php [QSA,NC,L]
```